# Argv and argc are undefined or null

Tags: php, command-line-arguments

When i try this in __construct:

```
var_dump($argc);
var_dump($argv);
var_dump($_SERVER["argv"]);
```

It returns error

> Undefined variable: argc and
>   Undefined variable: argv

and array

> (size=0)   empty

When i declare $argc and $argv in global it returns all null.

Also i am parsing arguments using nncron like this:

```
* * * * * php \php\class.xmlcontroler.php timeout=60

0 * * * * php \php\class.xmlcontroler.php timeout=3600
```

What is solution?

Comment: May be the register [register_argc_argv](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-argc-argv) has to be activated.

Comment: register_argc_argv
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

Answer (score 8):

`$argv` and `$argc` are only available in the global namespace. You would have to handle them as a parameter to your constructor.

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    var_dump($argv);
}
echo "global\n";
var_dump($argv);

echo "function\n";
foo();
```

Will provide:

```
global
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "a.php"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "123"
}
function
NULL
```

when called like this `php a.php 123`

**Update:** Class example

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public function __construct($argv)
    {
        // use $argv
    }
}

$foo = new Foo($argv);
```

Comment: so function foo() is not inside class? How can i call it if it is not inside class? foo() or $this->foo() does not works inside construct...

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP: $argc - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php):

> Note: This variable is not available when register_argc_argv is
> disabled.

So you have to enable the [`register_argc_argv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-argc-argv) flag in your PHP configuration file.