# PHP Cpanel Cron with Argv

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have a cron job that runs daily (for over a year) and suddenly does not work.

I have a cron job that looks like:

/usr/bin/php -q /home/tcanfarotta22/public_html/test_arg.php low_customer=2 high_customer=200

And then a PHP script that gets the variables like:

```
parse_str($argv[1], $params);
parse_str($argv[2], $params2);

$low_customer = $params['low_customer'];
$high_customer = $params2['high_customer'];
```

Now I am getting the following errors:

> [18-Jun-2018 10:38:01 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined
>   variable: argv in /home/tcanfarotta22/public_html/test_arg.php on line
>   5 [18-Jun-2018 10:38:01 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined
>   variable: argv in /home/tcanfarotta22/public_html/test_arg.php on line
>   6 [18-Jun-2018 10:38:01 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined
>   index: low_customer in /home/tcanfarotta22/public_html/test_arg.php on
>   line 8 [18-Jun-2018 10:38:01 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined
>   index: high_customer in /home/tcanfarotta22/public_html/test_arg.php
>   on line 9

Nothing has changed so I ma not sure what to do. Does anyone know?

Comment: Is that code in a function? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864332/argv-and-argc-are-undefined-or-null?rq=1

Comment: No -- it is not in a function. it is an older site. i am using PHP version 5.4

Comment: check the value of register_argc_argv using `<?= phpinfo() ?>`
also be aware that a lot of similar features has been removed from PHP <= 5.4 for performance reasons.

Comment: it was off and i turned it on but n o luck. Same error.

Comment: @JehadNasser do you know of the best alternate to argv?

Answer (score 0):

If the enabling of register_argc_argv does not fix the issue, **then maybe you are trying to access $argv within a class, in this case, you need to declare it as global before you can access it:**

```
global $argv;
```

BTW, I have tested your code (executed by the terminal) and it runs like a charm.

[image]

If this does not fix the issue, maybe then you need to put more details, also we need to know how you are testing?